# Python groupby threshold

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

I have a list of numbers and I need to group it. `itertools.grouby` work perfectly for sequences of same numbers but I need same behavior for numbers with a threshold (2-3%)

E.X: `lst = [1, 500, 19885, 19886, 19895, 90000000]`
and I expect `[[1], [500], [19885, 19886, 19895], [90000000]]`

Can you suggest me something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `groupby` but use a custom comparator:

```
class MyValue:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # 2% leeway
        return self.val*0.98 <= other.val <= self.val*1.02
```

And then:

```
for key, group in groupby(map(MyValue, values)):
    group_values = [el.val for el in group]
```

Note that this will keep the first value as "reference" so in a group you'll have the elements are are up to 2% away from the key/first value, but inside the group the deviation could go up to 4%.

This should be fine with the data you have shown, were the different groups are significantly apart but it wont be reliable with close groups.

Comment: very nice! For the equivalent result write `res = [[el.val for el in g] for key, g in groupby(map(MyValue, values))]` instead of the second code-block.

Answer (score 0):

Bucket them. You'd need to manually work out the breaks in advance. Can you sort then, in advance? That would make it easier.

Actually, if you use log, then a multiplicative threshold turns into a constant threshold, e.g. 0.98..1.02 in log-land ~= (-0.02, +0.02).
So, use the log of all your numbers.
You'll still need to bucket them before doing groupby.

If you want code, give us a better (random-seeded) reproducible example that has more numbers testing the corner-cases.

Comment: what u mean about bucket ? actually I cant sort it because order is necessary.

Comment: 'bucket' means 'divide the range into bins, and use the quantized value, for the purposes of grouping' - similar to what @Bakuriu showed. Just like in a histogram.